# Is it possible to load a Xib from another Xib without adding blank view to hierarchy

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, xib, nib

I'm aware there are ways to load a view from a nib and have one of its subviews load from a different nib. For instance, you can get the xib to load a custom UIView subclass as one of it's subviews by setting this class in the identity inspector, and then have this UIView subclass add a subview from a Xib in code. Essentially, the custom UIView subclass is just a proxy view, and the view hierarchy of this approach is the following:

**Parent View (loaded from Xib) -> proxy UIView subclass -> Child View (loaded from Xib)**

This method is described in a Medium post [here](https://medium.com/plated-engineering/adopting-safer-custom-view-initializers-from-interface-builder-51084eec0d08)

However, ideally I'd like to avoid the proxy view entirely as it has an adverse effect on performance **edit:** *to clarify I am not having performance issues, when I say adverse performance I just mean it's not ideal to add more views to the hierarchy as it uses more system resources, but the difference is probably imperceptible and I'm asking this question mainly out of curiosity*. I could achieve this through adding the view through code, but I'd prefer to use Xib's as it's easier to visualise constraints. I could also achieve this via only using one Xib, but I'd like to be able to use the child xib elsewhere in the application.

In my ideal world, the child view is a direct child of the parent view, with both being loaded from Xibs:

**Main View (loaded from Xib) -> Child View (loaded from Xib)**

The ideal way I'd like to be able to implement the direct relationship is by simply setting the class of the child xib (using the identity inspector) inside the parent xib. However, as far as I can tell the reason this doesn't work is because when the parent view is created from the parent xib, it doesn't even know there is a Xib for the child view, so it simply loads it programatically, and I don't believe there's any option to inform it to load a subview from a xib?

Another hypothetical solution is to force the child view to load from xib no matter where it was loaded from, as I believe that would eliminate the need for a proxy UIView subclass and thus solve my problem, but I don't know a way to do this and it might not be possible.

Please let me know any ideas! many thanks

Comment: "it has an adverse effect on performance" Could you talk a bit more about that part? What issue are we really trying to avoid here? When does this adverse issue arise and what form does it take, precisely? Thx

Comment: @matt that was vague of me so I will edit the post. There is no performance "problem" and I'm sure there is no real world difference, my interest in a solution here is mainly to do whether this is theoretically possible on the iOS platform or whether devs only choice is to add one more view to the hierarchy than would be ideal, which has an adverse (but a probably imperceptible) effect on performance. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: You could "clean up" the hierarchy manually later, but this could be more trouble than it is worth. I'm still not persuaded that a single extra view is such a disaster.

Comment: Also may I point out that "container view" architectures are useful in many contexts in iOS and no one describes them as bad; they are often quite necessary. Suppose you are in the Storyboard and you make a Container View with an Embed segue. That is an extra view _exactly like_ the one you are talking about here, but no one calls it disperformant; Apple themselves are _encouraging_ you to use this structure, right there in the storyboard. Your architecture is simply the "loose xib" version of that, with bare views instead of nested view controllers.

Comment: Also (sorry to rattle on) if you take a look at the view hierarchy of, say, a presented view controller using the View Debugger you will see _lots and lots_ of "blank" extra views right the way down the hierarchy, imposed by the runtime. In short, this is perfectly standard operating procedure. I think you are worrying about nothing. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: @matt haha thanks a bunch for the insight, my curiosity that drove me to ask this stemmed from me being surprised that there seemingly wasn't a way to avoid the extra view, so I thought I might be missing something obvious and just wanted to double check. Given your expertise it seems there isn't a good way to avoid the extra view so I'm very satisfied to add this proxy view to the hierarchy!

Comment: Yeah, I can think of a way, where the proxy view would rip itself out of the hierarchy and replace itself with the nib-loaded view, instead of embedding the nib-loaded view as its subview; but the potential complexities would be simply staggering, esp. in a world of autolayout constraints.